# Rails4, Turbolinks, and select2: Object [object Object] has no method 'select2'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-select2, turbolinks

Can someone help me with this, I get the error:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'select2'
```

If i'm go through a link using turbolinks.
But if I reload the page select2 works.

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require select2
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

**events.js.coffee**

```
loadAdress = (json) ->
    $("#event_adress").val json.adress + "\n" + (if json.zipcode? then json.zipcode else '') + ' ' + json.town
    $("#event_name").val json.name
    $("#event_cell_phone").val (if json.cellPhone? then '+45'+json.cellPhone else '') 
    $(".hidden").slideDown()

ready = ->
    if $("#event_contact_id").length > 0
        $("#event_contact_id").select2
            width: "element"
            placeholder: "Find kunde"
        $("#event_contact_id").on "select2-selecting", (e) ->
            $.ajax "/contacts/" + e.val + ".json",
            dataType: "json"
            success: loadAdress

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

I hope someone can help me out with this, because I have tried to solve this for hours now.

Comment: Did you solve this? If not, did you recently precompile your assets before the issues started?

Comment: Did you add `application.js` to `<body>`? Check [here](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/1582)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to use turbolinks and removed it.

Comment: Just did the same thing. I was thinking maybe it's be better to use something other than select2 but I just got annoyed with Turbolinks and got rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  #your stuff
```